Windows authentication in simple web service
I am trying to create a simple web service starting with the Visual Studio "ASP .NET Core Web API project template". The project wizard creates a weatherforecast service that works fine. After I changed localhost to the name of my computer I can also access the service remotely from another computer and from another user account. But when I activate "Windows Authentication" in the project template the resulting service is no longer accessible remotely. Remote access results in

InvalidOperationException: An anonymous request was received in between authentication handshake requests.

I tried the project template with authentication set to "None" -> everything's fine. Authentication set to "Windows" -> remote access results in "InvalidOperationException: An anonymous request was received in between authentication handshake requests.". Local access (via browser) still works.
I use Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.8.5.
This is what the service dumps into the output window of the debugger:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler: Error: An exception occurred while processing the authentication request.


System.InvalidOperationException: An anonymous request was received in between authentication handshake requests.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()


Could you please share your detailed error message? how you have configured windows auth in the api ? is both the machine is in the same network and under same domain name?

Both machines are in the same network under the same domain. Concerning windows auth configuration: I didn't configure anything, just selected authentication: windows in the project creation wizard.

My workaround was to switch to Http.sys (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys).
